# Do some aircraft windshields contain gold particles?

Tags: windscreen, canopy

I've heard that the windshields of some aircraft have gold particles, but I don't know why?

Comment: Agreed - the F-22 question could do with a more general title, and we'd be done.

Comment: actually, @egid, it question the F-22 question is a dup of could use a more general title and all would be good. :)

Comment: And FWIW, gold particles (at least in low concentrations) make red/ruby colored glass: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_coloring_and_color_marking#Striking_glasses

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo: The point I was trying to make is that (as with the F-22 in the link) a gold COLOR is not necessarily (or even probably) produced by actual gold.